# Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to run my project in android studio , but I am getting following issue.

**Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.2.71): No cached version available for offline mode**

It would be great , if I got the solution.Looking forward for your helpful suggestions

Comment: Looks like you switched Gradle into "Offline mode"

Comment: same error after switching to offline mode

Comment: Have you tried to run Gradle from the command line?

Comment: no , if it would be working solution than can you please suggest me how to setup from command line.It would be great

Comment: Open the Terminal window in IntelliJ and type ./gradlew build

Answer (score 7):

Gradle is in offline mode.

Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences).

In the left pane, click Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools >  Gradle. Check the Offline work checkbox off.

Click Apply or OK.

Comment: The Gradle setting is under `Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle`

Comment: I can't find the Offline work checkbox.

Answer (score 7):

Simple Steps:

1. Click File > Project Structure
2. Click Dependencies >
3. Find and Click org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.21 (or whatever your current version is)
4. Under Details > update section, click [update variable][update dependencies]
5. Click Ok

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Android Studio open project and then File > project Structure > Suggestions and update all file and then click on apply.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wwCW.png]

I think your adroid project maximum problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Switch off Gradle's offline mode:
Gradle settings -> Toggle offline mode
or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> offline mode

Answer (score 0):

Go to project level Gradle and change **$kotlin_version** to an updated version.

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case (Android Studio 4.1.3), click

"File" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files"

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had do disable proxy and activate the option **No proxy** in Android Studio.
Go to File->System Settings -> HTTP Proxy and enable **No proxy**. You can check the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you added the plugin in a forked branch.
When you imported the project from VCS you, by default, checkout the master branch not containing the plugin.

Simply checkout your forked branch (after having imported the project) then resync gradle and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

`In my project`

`In side add`

`build.gridle(Project)`

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
   id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
   //add externaly 
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false 
}
```

and goto file -> settings-> plugging -> and download kotlin

`woking Done Thanks.`