# Could not solve the problem of android gradle build for the first time

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I have the following errors when I first open my first android project file.

```
Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable.jar
```

I have no idea what to do next with it.

Comment: Your project built on Kotlin or java ?

Comment: My project is built in Kotlin

Comment: your system cant download jar file . please check your internet connection . if your internet connection is good maybe you must use VPN

Comment: Please check this question:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276111/could-not-download-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-jar

Comment: @Black4Guy I have through that questions and answers but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You are getting only    Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable.jar   this line in error ? or there are more messages ?

Answer (score 0):

File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Gradle
cancel Offline work

Answer (score 0):

I have used VPN to install that jar file and the problem is solved.

Thanks for everyone who was answering the questions for me.