# Flutter could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddedable-1.5.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.5.21.jar

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, kotlin

I'm creating an Flutter application.

Now I want to add Flutter OSM to project for working with maps. But after adding flutter_osm_plugin to **pubspec.yaml** I'm getting an error:

```
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_osm_plugin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_osm_plugin:classpath'.
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.5.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.5.21)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.5.21/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.5.21.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.5.21/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.5.21.jar'.
            > Connect to fodev.org:8118 [fodev.org/45.129.39.130] failed: Connection refused: connect
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':location'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             23,6s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.5.21.jar** downloading from browser. But I can't install this from Android Studio. I haven't an Antivirus.

What's problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot. I'v resolved the problem.

I changed a kotlin compiler version and choosed 'No Proxy' in HTTP Settings.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution.  Please consider "accepting" it; this will mark the question as "Closed" ... and help others with a similar problem find your solution more easily.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're probably building your Flutter app using Android Studio (vs. VSCode, or the Flutter CLI).  Please try the suggestions in this thread: [Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55276111/421195)

- Ensure you're not in offline mode:

  - Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences).
  - In the left pane, click Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle. Check the Offline work checkbox off.
  - Click Apply or OK.
- Update the library version:

  - Click Dependencies >
    Find and Click org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.21 (or whatever your current version is)
  - Under Details > update section, click [update variable] > [update dependencies]

Please confirm your build environment (A/S?); please let us know if you resolved the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Android Studio version 2020.3.1 (Arctic Fox) and I'm havent an 'Offline work' option.

Comment: I have all three of A/S, VSCode and the CLI.  My personal preference most of the time is VSCode.  Which probably wouldn't have any JetBrains dependencies.  Please try the "update library" version suggestion above.  "Update" every Jetbrains dependency you see, "clean" and "rebuild".  ALSO: Try File > project Structure > Suggestions and update all file and then click on apply. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wwCW.png]

Comment: Thanks. But I haven't "Suggestions" option. I will try to update for another way.

Comment: Q: Have you resolved the problem?  Q: Are you able to compile *OUTSIDE* of A/S?  For example, can you create a new Flutter project from the command line, copy in your lib\* source code and pubspec.yaml file, and then compile and run from the CLI (or, equivalently, from VSCode)?  Q: Can you [Edit] your post and show us your pubspec.yaml?  PS: I took a brief look at an A/S Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2 install I have on Ubuntu ... and it reminded me why I dislike A/S ;)